# Object is null when passed to web api in c#

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have created web api in asp.net mvc. What I want is to call that post method in web api from another project (website) in asp.net.

Here is my Class Vendor

```
[ModelBinder(typeof(VendorModelBinder))]
public class Vendor
{
    public string VenName { get; set; }
    public string VenCompany { get; set; }
}
```

Here is VendorModelBinder

```
public class VendorModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext.ModelType != typeof(Vendor))
        {
            return false;
        }
        Vendor result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Vendor>
           (actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
        bindingContext.Model = result;
        return true;
    }
```

Here is my VendorController

```
 public class VendorController : ApiController
{


    // POST: api/Vendor/5
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([ModelBinder]Vendor Ven)
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(" Data Source = DELL; Initial Catalog = EVENT; Integrated Security = True");
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[InsVendor]", con);
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", Ven.VenName);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@compnay", Ven.VenCompany);

        con.Open();
        int i = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        HttpResponseMessage message = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        message.Content = content;
        return message;
    }


}
```

Here I am calling the post method in web api

```
 static async Task<Uri> AddVendorAsync(AllVendor Ven)
{ 
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:56908/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        StringContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Ven), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("api/Vendor", content);

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();


        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Success");
        }

        // return URI of the created resource.
        return response.Headers.Location;


    }
}
```

Is the above procedure correct?
Because I am getting the null object at the Vendor Controller (Ven.VenName)

Kindly, help me on this one.
Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason that you're using your own model binder?

Comment: Also what is the structure of `AllVendor`?

Comment: Not any particular reason, I just went through some tutorials & this was the way to verify Vendor ojbect @Luke

Comment: The structure of AllVendor is same as Vendor. AllVendor is my class at client side @DavidG